# Prove\Disprove: If $L_1$ is not a CFL, and $L_2$ is finite, then $L_1 \cup L_2$ is not a CFL.

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language, context-free-grammar, finite-state-machine

I am getting ready for finals, and encountered this question in a past assignment. I haven't proved this then and I don't understand how I can prove it now.

Prove\Disprove: If $L_1$ is **not** a Context-Free language, and $L_2$ is finite, then $L_1 \cup L_2$ is **not** a Context-Free language.

My intuition says this is true, but we haven't really seen properties of none CFL's in the course, so i'm having a hard time coming up with a solution based solely on closure of operations on CFL's and RL's.

any helpful insight would be great, thank you!

Comment: Hint: Assuming that $L_1\cup L_2$ is CF and that $L_2$ is finite, what can we say about $L_1 = (L_1\cup L_2)\setminus L_2$?

Comment: Which closure properties of context-free and regular languages do you know?

Comment: @frabala I actually tried that direction!!
I got that $(L_1 \cap \bar{L_2}) \cup  (L_2 \cap \bar{L_2})=L_1 \cap \bar{L_2}$ is a CFL, but I don't see how this is a contradiction

Comment: @J.-E.Pin closure to union,intersection, complement, Kleen, concat with RL's.
and closure to concat,Kleen and union with other CFL's.

Comment: @Yoav You do not need that equation. Hint #2: A CFL minus a finite set should still be a CFL. Combine the two hints and you get a contradiction.